# How to use pillow library to access image files in sub-directories recursively?

Tags: python-imaging-library, python-3.6

I want to crop and resize multiple images in many sub-directories. The code works if the images are in the same directory, but fails to read from other directories.

I have tried using os.walk() module. It successfully iterate the files from all subdirectories, but the pillow's Image.open() function fails to access the images and thereby displaying error: "image.." not found.

```
import os
from PIL import Image

for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk('.'):
    for filename in files:
        t = filename.split(".")
        ext = t[-1]
        if ext in ["jpg"]:
            print(filename)
            coords = (500, 250, 810,720)
            image_obj = Image.open(filename)
            cropped_image = image_obj.crop(coords)
            resized_image =cropped_image.resize([227,227])
            # name = "./data2" + str(i) +".jpg"
            resized_image.save("new" + filename)
```

I expect the code to recursively crop and resize the images in all the sub-directories. The following error occurred.

```
frame0.jpg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "........./data2/cropitall.py", line 18, in <module>
    image_obj = Image.open(filename) #path of image to be cropped
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2652, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'frame0.jpg'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open the image you need the entire path to the file, not just file name.
Instead of

```
image_obj = Image.open(filename)
```

do

```
path = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
image_obj = Image.open(path)
```